# Outlook Web App Html Markup for Message body: New OWA vs Old OWA

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-app

I noticed that for the message body of Outlook Web Application; thus the result for `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()`, the HTML markup for the old OWA is complete (has html and body tag) while that of the New OWA is partial.

Is there a documentation for this change and a reason for this break in consistency?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the coercionType in getAsync. Please refer to:

[getAsync(coercionType, options, callback)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=office-js#getasync-coerciontype--options--callback-)

[Office.CoercionType enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.coerciontype?view=office-js)

Comment: I did set the coercionType. First i got it from `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getTypeAsync` then passed the result.value to `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` as the coercion type

Comment: Try setting the coercion type to Office.CoercionType.Html

Comment: That makes no difference. The body return for an empty message is <div></div>. I was expecting <html><body></body></html> (which is given by the old OWA).

Comment: We don't guarantee the uniformity of the HTML code being returned across the clients. New OWA is considered as a different client. Also, please tell me your scenario so that we can suggest any alternative approach.